# What is the difference between materialized view in clickhouse and postgres

Tags: clickhouse

I'm new to Clickhouse, and I was trying to use its materialized view feature. However, it seems that there are significant differences between Clickhouse's and Postgres' materialized views.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are some differences between ClickHouse's and Postgres' materialized views.

One significant difference is that ClickHouse's materialized views are refreshed incrementally, while Postgres' materialized views are refreshed completely. In ClickHouse, when a materialized view is created, it starts with an empty dataset, and data is incrementally added to it as new data is inserted into the source table. In contrast, Postgres' materialized views are always populated with the entire data set of the source table at the time of the refresh.

Another difference is that ClickHouse's materialized views can be created with an arbitrary query, while Postgres' materialized views must be created with a SELECT statement. This means that ClickHouse's materialized views can include subqueries, joins, and other more complex constructs, while Postgres' materialized views are more limited in their functionality.

Finally, ClickHouse's materialized views can be used for distributed processing, which can help to improve performance in large-scale systems. Postgres' materialized views are more limited in their ability to handle distributed data processing.

Overall, while there are some similarities between ClickHouse's and Postgres' materialized views, there are also significant differences in their functionality and usage. It's important to carefully consider the requirements of your particular use case when choosing which system to use.

Comment: from what you are saying I think the materialized view in Clickhouse is like a trigger am I right?

Comment: No, a materialized view in ClickHouse is not exactly like a trigger. While both materialized views and triggers are used in databases, they serve different purposes

Comment: materialized views are used to improve query performance by precomputing and storing query results, while triggers are used to execute certain actions automatically in response to database events.

Comment: matView in CH is exactly a trigger https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

Comment: A materialized view is a database object that contains the precomputed results of a query. It's like a table that is populated and updated automatically based on the results of a specific SELECT statement. Materialized views are useful when you need to store the results of a complex query that takes a long time to execute, so that you can retrieve the results quickly without having to execute the query each time.

Comment: On the other hand, a trigger is a database object that is executed automatically in response to a specific event, such as an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operation on a table. Triggers can be used to enforce business rules, validate data, or perform other actions based on the data being modified